# How to implement a rolling_pct_change(period) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to implement a rolling pct_change(period) method in pandas?

I have a series 's':

```
>>>s
   1999-03-01    1.0139
   1999-03-02    1.0053
   1999-03-03    1.0069
   1999-03-04    0.9963
   1999-03-05    1.0029
   1999-03-08    1.0052
   1999-03-09    1.0039
   ...
```

I am looking for a quick and flexible implementation that gives me something like a

```
>>>s.rolling_pct_change(period=3)
   1999-03-01    NaN
   1999-03-02    NaN
   1999-03-03    NaN
   1999-03-04    -0.0173587138771 
   1999-03-05    -0.00238734706058
   1999-03-08    -0.00168835038236
   1999-03-09    0.00762822443039
```

where each `element = (element[day] - element[day-period]) / element[day-period]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pct_change()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) method it self?

```
In [265]: s.pct_change(3)
Out[265]:
                 val
date
1999-03-01       NaN
1999-03-02       NaN
1999-03-03       NaN
1999-03-04 -0.017359
1999-03-05 -0.002387
1999-03-08 -0.001688
1999-03-09  0.007628
```

Or, build up using [`shift()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)

```
In [252]: s/s.shift(3)-1
Out[252]:
                 val
date
1999-03-01       NaN
1999-03-02       NaN
1999-03-03       NaN
1999-03-04 -0.017359
1999-03-05 -0.002387
1999-03-08 -0.001688
1999-03-09  0.007628
```